# Use artist image as background blur

Tags: android

I have searched the net and have no idea how to use the artist image as background to itself
  Some apps that use this are gaana and wynk music player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Fast Blur library by, **Mario Klingemann**

```
public class Fastblur {
    public Bitmap Fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {

        // Stack Blur v1.0 from
        // http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
        //
        // Java Author: Mario Klingemann <mario at quasimondo.com>
        // http://incubator.quasimondo.com
        // created Feburary 29, 2004
        // Android port : Yahel Bouaziz <yahel at kayenko.com>
        // http://www.kayenko.com
        // ported april 5th, 2012

        // This is a compromise between Gaussian Blur and Box blur
        // It creates much better looking blurs than Box Blur, but is
        // 7x faster than my Gaussian Blur implementation.
        //
        // I called it Stack Blur because this describes best how this
        // filter works internally: it creates a kind of moving stack
        // of colors whilst scanning through the image. Thereby it
        // just has to add one new block of color to the right side
        // of the stack and remove the leftmost color. The remaining
        // colors on the topmost layer of the stack are either added on
        // or reduced by one, depending on if they are on the right or
        // on the left side of the stack.
        //
        // If you are using this algorithm in your code please add
        // the following line:
        //
        // Stack Blur Algorithm by Mario Klingemann <mario@quasimondo.com>

        Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;

        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }

        yw = yi = 0;

        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;

            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

                sir = stack[i + radius];

                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];

                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }

                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
                pix[yi] = (0xff000000 & pix[yi]) | (dv[rsum] << 16)
                        | (dv[gsum] << 8) | dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];

                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }

        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        return (bitmap);
    }
}
```

To use,

```
Fastblur fb = new Fastblur();
Bitmap blurred_image = fb.Fastblur(your_bitmap, radius_of_blur_amount);
```

This will return a blurred image. Now set the `blurred_image` to your `ImageView` and enjoy your blurred background.